# Modify Msgbox Form with comma

Tags: excel, vba, msgbox

I write a VBA CODE that's filter a column and return the result in msgbox. The problem is: the msgbox does not show me all the values because the column contains more than 100 values.

My question is: how can I modify the form of the msgbox and separate it with comma.

Many thanks

```
Sub Fstr()
    Dim str As String
    Dim j As Integer
    j = 2
    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Count
        If Cells(i, 6) = "CEM" Then
            str = str & CStr(Cells(i, 2)) & vbCrLf
            'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BDD").Range("B" & j) = Cells(i, 4)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox str
End Sub
```

Comment: Use a userform.

Comment: msgbox is show from an userform

Comment: Maybe I should have clarified. Use a userform *instead* of a msgbox.

Comment: You could write the results to a string. Share your code so someone can show you how to do it.

Comment: You could experiment a little by replacing `vbCrLf` with e.g. `", "` or `vbTab`. On the other hand, what is the use of showing a hundred values in a message box?

Comment: Side note: avoid using `str` as a variable since that shadows the [`Str`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/str-function) function.

Comment: If you have that much output, consider a more useful one that a MsgBox. You could spawn a new worksheet and dump the values there, otherwise as others suggested if you want a custom message box, you can _make it_ with a userform.

Comment: Hey , i don't how can i make it with a userform

Answer (score 0):

To add a user form and show the str:

- Go to VBA Editor window
- Insert a UserForm
- Add a TextBox from Controls
- Right click the textbox and click properties
- from the properties change the Multiline = True
- You can show the form using the below code

In Module1:

```
Sub Fstr()

Dim str As String
Dim j As Integer
j = 2
For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Count
    If Cells(i, 6) = "CEM" Then
        str = str & CStr(Cells(i, 2)) & vbCrLf
        'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BDD").Range("B" & j) = Cells(i, 4)
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i
'MsgBox str

UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = str
UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

[image]